# How to close tcp connection using SpyMemcached client?

Tags: java, spymemcached

I am using memcache through SpyMemcached client . I want to ask that how can i close the tcp connection after using it. I dont know the method .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `shutdown()` ([apidocs](http://dustin.sallings.org/java-memcached-client/apidocs/net/spy/memcached/MemcachedClient.html#shutdown())) function in the MemcachedClient class.

Comment: this method requires 2 arguments . I want to know what are these arguments?

Comment: There are 2 shutdown functions. One takes 0 arguments and causes the client to shutdown immediately. If you have any async ops that have been sent then they may be cancelled. The second shutdown function takes a timeout value and a timeout unit. For example, shutdown(1, TimeUnit.Seconds) will cause the client to wait up to one second for any outstanding operations to complete before shutting down.